# Not Getting Updated data when using threading

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, linq

In my program there are two method one is start processing and second is end processing.

```
Public void StartProcessing()
{
    Thread.Sleep(30000)
    bool isActive = _repository.FindBy(s=>s.UId == 1).isActive  //Linq Query 
}

Public void EndProcessing()    
{
    //Update data
}
```

So when i call `StartProcessing()` method it wait for 30 second and after 30 sec it returns data from sql. So now the problem is that when i am updating data before 30 second, it's not returning me updated data.
Please give me solution of this.

Answer (score 2):

1)Don't reuse your Context (I assume you use EF) in many threads.Create a new context/repository in each thread
2)Don't use threads,use Tasks (Task Parallel Library )

I guess FindBy probably checks the loaded Items first,that's why you get "old" data.
If you follow "1" your problem will probably be solved.
If not,you probably don't update your user....